# How can I return a newly created entity along with it's relationship with Nest.js/TypeORM?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am having trouble trying to figure out the best way to return a newly created entity along with its relationship(s).

Alone, each route that I have is working properly. Meaning, all CRUD operations work great. If I do a `GET` on the entity, I am also getting the relationship back as expected.

The issue I am stumbling with is, when a new entity is created--I am returning that entity. For example:

```
const foo = this.create();

foo.relationshipId = relationshipId;
foo.bar = bar;
foo.baz = baz;
foo.uuid = uuidv4();

try {
    await foo.save();
} catch (error) {
    // this.logger.error(`Failed to create the foo: ${error.stack}`);

    throw new InternalServerErrorException();
}

return foo;
```

If I log what `foo` is, I get back something that looks like this:

```
foo: {
    relationshipId: 1,
    bar: 'example',
    baz: 'example',
    uuid: '123-asdf-example'
}
```

What I need is to also include the actual related model/entitiy. Something like this:

```
foo: {
    relationshipId: 1,
    related: {
        some: 'property',
        another: 'example',
    },
    bar: 'example',
    baz: 'example',
    uuid: '123-asdf-example'
}
```

If I do a "regular" `GET` for that entity I *do* get the related entity back with it (exactly as the example above). It's only at the `create` method I am not returning the relationship.

How can I return the newly created entity along with the relationship? Do I need to do a `GET` on the new entity? Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you for any suggestions!

**UPDATE/SOLUTION**

Here is what ended up working for me (and also fits perfectly to what @Schutt suggested). This is my `foo.repository.ts` file:

```
...

const foo = this.create();

foo.bar = bar;
foo.uuid = uuidv4();

try {
    await foo.save();
} catch (error) {
    // this.logger.error(`Failed to create the foo: ${error.stack}`);

    throw new InternalServerErrorException();
}

return await this.findOne({
    where: { id: foo.id },
    relations: ['related'],
});
```

I am now getting the newly created entity as well as the related entitiy.
In my frontend, I can display something like this now:

```
{{ foo.relation.name }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible to load the relationship while you `.save()` your entity.

You have to re-fetch the entity. (i.e. with `foo.findOne(..)` there you can specify the `relations` property and this will then load your relation automatically)

Comment: I was just coming back to this. Thank you so much for your suggestion! I have updated my question to show what I ended up with. There's been **many** times I've missed the built-in/obvious way.